# Pyspark dataframe to insert an array of array's element to each row

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to put this `arrays = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]` into another column with its array element.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, "foo"), (2, "bar")], ["id", "name"])
+---+----+
| id|name|
+---+----+
|  1| foo|
|  2| bar|
+---+----+
```

The desired result

```
+---+----+---------+
| id|name|  numbers|
+---+----+---------+
|  1| foo|[1, 2, 3]|
|  2| bar|[4, 5, 6]|
+---+----+---------+
```

How to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, "foo", (1,2,3)), (2, "bar",(3,4,5))], ["id", "name", "my_array"])
>>> df.show()
+---+----+---------+                                                            
| id|name| my_array|
+---+----+---------+
|  1| foo|[1, 2, 3]|
|  2| bar|[3, 4, 5]|
+---+----+---------+
```

Or maybe you want to join the data:

```
#create a data frame
 df1 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(arrays).toDF()
#use columns to build the array back
 df1 = df1.select( F.array( [ col for col in df1.columns ]).alias("arrays" ))
>>> from pyspark.sql.window import Window
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number
# add a silly sort so the data remains unchanged in order
>>> windowSpec  = Window.orderBy(lit(1))
# add a rownumber to your array.
>>> dfNumbers.withColumn("row_number",row_number().over(windowSpec)) \
...     .show(truncate=False)
23/01/27 08:45:25 WARN WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.
+---------+----------+
|arrays   |row_number|
+---------+----------+
|[1, 2, 3]|1         |
|[4, 5, 6]|2         |
+---------+----------+
>>> dfNumbers = dfNumbers.withColumn("row_number",row_number().over(windowSpec)) 
>>> dfNumbers.join(df,dfNumbers.row_number == df.id).show() 
23/01/27 08:47:27 WARN WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.
+---------+----------+---+----+
|   arrays|row_number| id|name| 
+---------+----------+---+----+
|[1, 2, 3]|         1|  1| foo|
|[4, 5, 6]|         2|  2| bar|
+---------+----------+---+----+
```

This will make sure you are using Spark tools to join data(dataframe), not python tools(array).  I'm assuming it's ok to not have a partition as you are using an array which means it should fit in memory.  You should look into maintaining the array as a dataframe in the future.

or you could just use python to help formulate:

```
>>> agg = []
>>> count = 0
>>> for i in arrays:
...  agg.append( [ count , i ] )
...  count += 1
... 
>>> dfNumbers = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(agg).toDF(["id","arrays"])
>>> dfNumbers.show()
+---+---------+
| id|   arrays|
+---+---------+
|  0|[1, 2, 3]|
|  1|[4, 5, 6]|
+---+---------+
    >>> dfNumbers.join(df,dfNumbers.row_number == df.id).show() 
    23/01/27 08:47:27 WARN WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.
    +---------+----------+---+----+
    |   arrays|row_number| id|name| 
    +---------+----------+---+----+
    |[1, 2, 3]|         1|  1| foo|
    |[4, 5, 6]|         2|  2| bar|
    +---------+----------+---+----+
```

Comment: I mean to iterate the array to insert the existing dataframe. Not to create the dataframe.

Comment: Updated to reflect your use case

Comment: Updated to be even simpler